# http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 Forbidden using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I want to do a real time chat, with websocket/pusher.

1. Installed `laravel websockets` by following the command: `composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets`
2. Publish it by using: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSocketsServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"`
3. `php artisan migrate`
4. `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSocketsServiceProvider" --tag="config"` (I configure file `config/websocket.php`)
5. Installed laravel pusher: `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"`
6. Uncommented `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in `config/app.php`
7. Created a `ChatEvent` event
8. Launched websockets server by: `php artisan websockets:serve`
9. Opened link `http://localhost/jwtchat/public/laravel-websockets` then connect and everything works fine

I run `php artisan tinker`:

> event(new App\Events\ChatEvent('hello'))

It works very well, but when I try `http://localhost/jwtchat/public/broadcasting/auth` in postman, it gives me `403 Forbidden` error.

in payload it return me:

```
socket_id: 726245173.481815034
channel_name: presence-chat
```

##### `.env`

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher 
PUSHER_APP_ID=XXXXX
PUSHER_APP_KEY=YYYYY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=ZZZZ
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu
```

##### `broadcasting.php`

```php
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'http'
    ],
],
```

##### `websockets.php`

```php
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

##### `ChatEvent.php`

```
class ChatEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $mesage;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('chat');
    }
```

Comment: Please, DO NEVER SHARE KEYS... you will have to refresh the keys RIGHT NOW or you will have serious security issues... You must never access your Laravel app using `public` in the URL, so you have it misconfigured on your web server. The web server document root must be pointing to the `public` folder, so your URL should be `jwtchat/broadcasting/auth`

Comment: @matiaslauriti thx for u answer but when i try `http://localhost/jwtchat/public/broadcasting/auth`  give me `404Not Found` error

Comment: I exactly said you have to do the opposite, use `jwtchat/broadcasting/auth`, not `public`